# Why does Java's FileInputStream read() take parameter while Oracle's document says it doesn't?

Tags: java, oracle

I am reading a Java's exam prep book. I am confused when I read the following example:

```
byte [] magicNumber = {( byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0xFE, (byte) 0xBA, (byte) 0xBE}; 
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( fileName)) {  
    byte[] u4buffer = new byte[ 4]; 
    if( fis.read( u4buffer) != − 1) { 
        if( Arrays.equals( magicNumber, u4buffer)) { 
            System.out.printf(" The magic number for passed file %s matches that of a .class file", fileName); 
        } else { 
            System.out.printf(" The magic number for passed file %s does not match that of a .class file", fileName); 
        } 
    }
} catch( FileNotFoundException fnfe) { 
    System.err.println(" file does not exist with the given file name "); 
} catch( IOException ioe) { 
    System.err.println(" an I/ O error occurred while processing the file"); 
}
```

Here what does this mean: ***read( u4buffer)*** ?

Comment: What Oracle document? Have you heard about method overloading?

Comment: [It's right here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte[]))

Comment: I mean Oracle's online reference material. Yes, but the given example doesn't define the overloaded read method.

Comment: The example doesn't have to define anything, the FileInputStream class is a core Java class. Once imported, it comes with everything in it (including overloaded methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the documentation of [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)

The `read` method is overloaded twice with different parameters set.

And you may want to read more about [method overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686466/what-is-method-overloading).

Comment: You're welcome, always check the javadoc when questions arise about a core Java class :) (or any class for that matter, good libraries are always documented).