# Pow method inside calculator app

Tags: android

I am building basic calculator app, with sqrt and pow options. 
I want to add pow method to my app.I can do it simply to my method bellow, but it asks me for two Strings.I need this problem to be solved by using only one String.So user can enter number 4 and POW result is 16.

github for code : https://github.com/adnxy/CalculatorAt

Method for operating, using two Strings:

```
private double operate(String a, String b, String op) {
    switch (op) {
        case "+":
            return Double.valueOf(a) + Double.valueOf(b);
        case "-":
            return Double.valueOf(a) - Double.valueOf(b);
        case "x":
            return Double.valueOf(a) * Double.valueOf(b);
        // case "p":
        //   return Double.parseDouble(a) * Double.parseDouble(a);
        case "s":
            return Math.sqrt(Double.valueOf(a));
        case "÷":
            try {
                return Double.valueOf(a) / Double.valueOf(b);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Calc", e.getMessage());
            }
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}
```

I already make two methods: onClickPow and getResultPow.
My method getResultPow is not working when I click Pow inside App.Can somebody help me with getResultPow?

```
 public void onClickPow(View v) {
    if (display == "") return;
    if (!getResultPow("String a")) return;
    _screen.setText(display + "\n" + String.valueOf(result));
}


 private boolean getResultPow(String a) {

    //1.st case, all blank
    if (display == " " && currentOperator == " " && result == " ") return false;

    //2.nd case, 1 number entered
    if (currentOperator == "") return false;
    if (result == " ") return false;
    if (display != " ") {
        result = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(a) * Double.parseDouble(a));
        //_screen.setText(display + "\n" + String.valueOf(result));
        updateScreen();
        return true;
    }

    //3.rd case, two numbers entered, they need to call + and then pow 
    if (result == " ") return false;
    if (display != " " && currentOperator != " ") {
        result = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(a) + Double.parseDouble(a));
        result = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(a) * Double.parseDouble(a));
        //_screen.setText(display + "\n" + String.valueOf(result));
        updateScreen();
        return true;
    }
    if (currentOperator == "") return false;
    String[] operation = display.split(Pattern.quote(currentOperator));
    if (operation.length < 2) return false;
    result = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(a) * Double.parseDouble(a));
    return true;
    //return onClickPow();
}
```

Comment: What is this line means? if (!getResultPow("String a"))

Comment: power should also have 2 paramters ... 4^2 = 16, 4^3 = 64 ... now it should fit your `operate(String a, String b, String op)` method

Comment: @Selvin it should have 1 String param , when I enter 4 (4*4) = 16

Comment: @HuyN if getresult is false, return. If it is true, it will setText to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question you just need to use that same value two times for example:

```
input = Double.valueOf(tvNum.getText().toString());//Example value: 2

input2= Double.valueOf(tvNum.getText().toString());//Example value: 2

Double result = Math.pow(input,input2);//so this should do 2*2 = 4
```

Answer (score -1):

With OverLoading in OOP, you can create multiple method with the same name (the number of paramaters can difference). See this article: [What is method overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686466/what-is-method-overloading)